# How to find the next closest clustering for hierarchal clustering (in R)?

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering

I'm using hierarchical clustering to group together items using the `hclust()` and `cutree()` functions, but each cluster as a whole needs to fit certain conditions.  Because of this, I was wondering if it's possible to ask the `hclust()` function to find the next closest cluster given that we want a certain number of groups. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you plot the cluster dendogram you should be able to see how close clusters are I think. Try `plot(hclust(dist(iris [,1:4])))`. [This](https://www.r-bloggers.com/hierarchical-clustering-in-r-2/) can also help.

Comment: You can use `cutree` and set the number of clusters you desire.